# Reusing head gasket for 1985 mitsibushi pajero

Tags: mitsubishi

Recently i have repair my Mitsubishi pajero engine and used it for almost not more than 8days. Unfortunately the crankshaft broke on the way i was driving 100km far from my home. Now i bought new crankshaft, and the gasket should be uninstall to check whether the connecting rod has a problems or not.
Can i reuse the head gasket or buy a new one?
Thank you.

Comment: Still not sure why you need to remove the head?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't re-use a gasket, you're unit is turbocharged so you'll most likely be running more boost and will have a chance to crack it under pressure. Make you're own, take it out, and visit a local welder, or auto zone- use a kit for making your own gasket/flange. see youtube.

Comment: This is bad advice, unless you are just not describing what you mean very well.  I would advise that you make your answer a lot clearer.

Comment: No, I won't make it clearer. We are talking about re-using a gasket vs. making a new one- I suggest you re-read the question and figure out what is being asked. Let me clear up the issue: The issue is reusing a gasket or not? Sometimes these cars are exotic so parts are scare. Making a new gasket is an ideal fit for him/her. Well, why? Because parts are scare; these cars are shipped far from the place of where made. I hope this helps. I would still use a new gasket, incase the old is cracked- overheating can cause or other sorts of problems if a gasket doesn't seal properly on a turbo unit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a wise choice to reused the head gasket.  First of all they aren't all that expensive especially compared to the other costs you will incur fixing a broken crankshaft.  Secondly, while you MAY get away with it, chances are the old one will leak and you'll find yourself having to replace it anyway.

BTW, a broken crank is an uncommon issue.  Usually they are caused by another problem such as a seized piston or failed/spun bearing.

Comment: BTW, the old crankshaft fixed on the engine was not standard and it worn and repaired to a sizes of 75mm.and the spun bearings are the same.